# how to solve NSInternalInconsistencyException?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5, custom-cell

I am getting an error when I try to show custom cell on my tableView. I have a nibFile connected with cells but I always get thread sigbart here

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellForOffers" owner:self options:nil];
```

I don't know why, and my cell for row at index implementation is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellForOffers";
    CellForOffers *cell =(CellForOffers *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellForOffers" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


        appDC * application = [dataArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        cell.namelbl.text=application.o_name;

        cell.descriptionlbl.text=application.o_description;

        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:application.o_image_url]];


    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual crash message you are seeing. There is more detail in there than you are giving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add nib with its class like bellow...

```
cell = (CellForOffers *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```